# run hyperledger project but peer.address not configured

Tags: hyperledger

I use golang to write a smart contract and want to test that on my debian. After `go install myproject.go`, I go to `$GOBIN` path and run `myproject.go`. I got this error.

> 10:13:14.959 [shim] CRIT : peer.address not configured, can't connect to peer

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have started your peer in dev mode, you need to specify the following two environment variables before starting your chaincode.

```
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=<peer IP or hostname>:30303 
export CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=<unique name to identify chaincode>
./myproject
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following two environment variables while running the chaincode,

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc 
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303
```

use the id name, ip and port number provided by your `peer` service.

Your final command should look like this,

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./yourAppName
```